# Opera Browser | overflow: auto | Bug?

Tags: html, browser, scroll, overflow, opera

Is there a bug in the current Opera Browser (Version 66.0.3515.44)?

When I open https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp and go to the section "overflow: auto" or "overflow: scroll" there is a little symbol on the left top corner (see the red circle).

But just in the Opera Browser. In Microsoft Edge, there is no bug.

[image]

Do you have the same problem? Is there a solution for it?
I have no found any search results, but also I have  no idea, how I can call this symbol :).

Comment: Shouldn't you [report a bug](https://help.opera.com/en/computer-bug-wizard/)?

Comment: I have reported the bug via the form. In the meantime I have found a solution. With another scrollbar style, there is no symbol on the left top corner. That is no solution for the reason. But it can help.

Comment: See <https://forums.opera.com/topic/38175/div-artifacts-in-66-0-35> for discussion.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this bug. This is not that distracting, but it is good to know that there is no background activity going on (at first I thought that this is an artefact of some dangerous script/extension)

Comment: I was also confused at first and I first looked to see if I had something wrong in the css file. I also looked at the beta of the Opera browser, there the bug is fixed.